# form:checkbox not working in Spring MVC JSP page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, checkbox, data-binding

I have the following Model class:

```
public class BlocchettiScratchCards implements Serializable {
      ...
      private boolean flagNuovaGestione;

      public boolean isFlagNuovaGestione() {
        return flagNuovaGestione;
      }

      public void setFlagNuovaGestione(boolean flagNuovaGestione) {
        this.flagNuovaGestione = flagNuovaGestione;
      }
}
```

and the Bean class:

```
public class BlocchettiScratchCardsBean implements Serializable {
      ...
      private boolean flagNuovaGestione;
      public boolean isFlagNuovaGestione() {
        return flagNuovaGestione;
      }

      public void setFlagNuovaGestione(boolean flagNuovaGestione) {
        this.flagNuovaGestione = flagNuovaGestione;
      }
}
```

in the JSP we have a `<form:form>` tag with the following:

```
<form:checkbox path="flagNuovaGestione"/>
```

The controller class initialize the property as follows:

```
BlocchettiScratchCardsBean elencoCards = new BlocchettiScratchCardsBean();        
elencoCards.setFlagNuovaGestione(true);
```

but when the page is loaded, the checkbox is not checked by default as I expect.

Inspecting HTML of page, I see the following:

```
<input id="flagNuovaGestione1" name="flagNuovaGestione" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="_flagNuovaGestione" value="on">
```

but the checked property is not set.

Why do I have this behaviour and how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution on my own. 
The problem was into the Controller class, in particular the instruction that adds the `formBean` into the jsp view was executed before the setting of the `flagNuovaGestione` boolean variable.

This was the old / not working code:

```
BlocchettiScratchCardsBean elencoCards = new BlocchettiScratchCardsBean();        
view.addObject("formBean", elencoCards);
elencoCards.setFlagNuovaGestione(true);
```

and the following is the right one:

```
BlocchettiScratchCardsBean elencoCards = new BlocchettiScratchCardsBean();            
elencoCards.setFlagNuovaGestione(true);
view.addObject("formBean", elencoCards);
```